# Как правильно записать пункт в .gitignore

Tags: gitignore

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно игнорить шаблоны для папок. Вот например я хочу игнорить папки которые начинаются как "build-"

[image: список папок]

Comment: `build-*/`......

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)

Comment: @entithat, пожалуйста, оформите как ответ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An asterisk `*` matches anything except a slash. [Подробнее.](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format)

```
build-*/
```